# How to integrate Active Directory/AWS IAM to EKS Kubernetes Dashboard access

Tags: kubernetes, active-directory, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, kubernetes-dashboard

We have a Kubernetes dashboard created in the kube-system namespace in AWS EKS. We are allowing the accesss to the Kubernetes dashboard by allowing the IP on the inbound rule of the Kubernetes Dashboard ALB security group. Is there a way we can integrate active directory or AWS IAM users authenticate to the Kubernetes dashboard instead of IP based access?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we are integrating AD for K8S dashboard. You have to configure DEX as an OIDC provider and use the connecter as LDAP.

Below are link which can guide you

Dex.
https://github.com/dexidp/dex

What is dex?
https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-single-sign-one-less-identity/

Guide to configure
https://theithollow.com/2020/01/21/active-directory-authentication-for-kubernetes-clusters/